# Flask Sessions - Session isn't always removed on logout (Works sometimes)

Tags: python, flask

I have a javascript fetch call to an api (on a different domain) and I'm passing along credentials. On the other Python Flask API, I have CORS and 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' set to true on all requests.

Python Webservice

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.getenv('SESSION_SECRET')
app.config.from_object(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    return response


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@captcha_check
def login():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)  # Force body to be read as JSON
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')

    # Authenticate users account and password
    if auth.verify_password(email, password):
        # Password is correct, return temporary session ID
        username_query = db.get_username_by_email(email)
        if username_query['found']:
            session['email'] = email
            return jsonify({'status': 200, 'email': email}), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({'status': 404, 'error': 'user-email-not-found'}), 404
    else:
        # Incorrect password specified, return Unauthorized Code
        return jsonify({'status': 401, 'error': 'incorrect-password'}), 401


@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    print(session, file=sys.stdout)
    session.clear()
    print(session.pop('email', None), file=sys.stdout)
    return jsonify({'status': 200}), 200
```

Javascript fetch call

```js
async function signInPost(data) {
    const response = await fetch(serverAddress + '/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    // Wait for response from server, then parse the body of the response in json format
    return await response.json();
}


async function signOutPost() {
    const response = await fetch(serverAddress + '/logout', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        },
        credentials: 'include'
    });
    return await response.json();
}
```

I know the cookie is being set with login becuase I have other endpoints that check the status of the cookie to see if a person is signed in or not. What I'm confused about is why this doesn't always invalidate the cookie. On chrome the network syas the status of the first api call is "(cancled)", but then sometimes if I click it one or two more times it will eventually sign out. On Firefox and Safari it will esentially never sign me out.

Flask is getting the api calls and returning a 200 status, but the browsers are not respecting what is being returned.

My current assumption is that it has something to do with the OPTIONS method that get's called in advance blocking the request, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you pass in your config.py file something like this

```
CORS_SUPPORTS_CREDENTIALS = True
```

instead of passing in the requests?

Comment: I tried adding it to my python script as a header that should be returned after each request, and I also added it to my js fetch function as a header. The issue still persists where the first request get's blocked.